# NTSTATUS could not be resolved

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, nt-native-api

im trying to make a program witch will get command line of proces by a Process id. Im using eclipse c++ and mingw compiler

So i found a 1 tutorial how to do that, and it needs **ntstatus** so like in tutorial i included `#include <ntstatus.h>`

And i added first part of code what is:

```
typedef NTSTATUS (NTAPI *_NtQueryInformationProcess)(
    HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    DWORD ProcessInformationClass,
    PVOID ProcessInformation,
    DWORD ProcessInformationLength,
    PDWORD ReturnLength
    );
```

And im gettig this 3 errors:

```
expected primary-expression before '__attribute__

Type 'NTSTATUS' could not be resolved

typedef 'NTSTATUS' is initialized (use decltype instead)
```

On this line: `typedef NTSTATUS (NTAPI *_NtQueryInformationProcess)(`

I googled about this problem, and i colud not find it...

Comment: Instead of using internal or undocumented or kernel API functions (whatever), consider just using e.g. wmic. E.g. `WMIC PROCESS WHERE Name="notepad.exe" GET CommandLine`.

Comment: Ahh, im not so good in c++ so i dont even know what is wmic...

Comment: That's a Windows command, typed in a command interpreter like cmd.exe or powershell.exe. It's short for Windows Management Isometing Csomethingelse. The functionality can also be accessed via COM and Automation interfaces (pure COM easiest for C++, Automation for script languages).

Comment: Thanks bro, i got the process command line via: wmic process PROCESSID, if you want now go and post answer :)

Comment: Your example compiles fine for me when I include `<windows.h>`, and at least it doesn't mind `NTSTATUS` when I include `<ntstatus.h>`. What version of g++ are you using ?

Comment: Use mingw_w64 and #include winternl.h so you don't have to do any of this.

Answer (score 5):

NTSTATUS is defined in

```
#include <winternl.h>
```

as

```
typedef _Return_type_success_(return >= 0) LONG NTSTATUS;
```

and its values are defined in

```
#include <ntstatus.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thee also needs to be a `_WIN32_WINNT`  defined, otherwise `<winternl.h>` will generate no code. My DLL project only spat `Syntax error: NTSTATUS`. How to fix:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>
```